# How to update item permission using SP2013 workflow?

Tags: workflow

Previously I have Nintex workflow experience. Now I come to a project do not have Nintex. We only have SP2013 OOB Workflow (workflow 2010). May I know is it possible to change an item permission using basic workflow (without coding with Visual Studio)

The step is like below:
1. user apply for software download
2. system notify admin to approve/reject the application.
3. If approved, permission will be granted to the applicant.
4. user will receive an email with link. Then he can download the software

Any reference link is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much possible and you will find lot of article for it on internet. I am providing below link which shows you screen by screen

http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

Also there is released a set of SharePoint 2013 Workflow activities to work with permissions - [Artezio SharePoint 2013 Workflow Activities](https://sp2013workflowactivities.codeplex.com/). Please check.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. It is very close to what I need. I think I will stick with SP2010 workflow as 2013 one seems not very well developed.

Comment: If it works then mark as answer